# Using python's super() to inherit attributes

Tags: python, inheritance, attributes, python-2.x, super

Python 2.7.10

Hi,

All I want to do is inherit super class attributes, a standard objected oriented thing to want to do.

From what I can find online here and elsewhere, this should work:

```
class SubClass(MyParentClass):
   def __init__(self):
      super(SubClass, self).__init__()
```

That gets:

```
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

How is that not a type?  I press the issue with:

```
class SubClass(MyParentClass):
   def __init__(self):
      super(type(self.__class__), self).__init__()
```

That gets:

```
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

I can't wrap my brain around that one.  An object instance isn't an instance of the type of its class?  How is that even possible?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might be something just in python 2.7, because it works fine for me in python 3.6.

Comment: If `SubClass.__init__` doesn't do anything else besides call another `__init__`, it can be omitted altogether. The method itself will be inherited and called.

Answer (score 3):

In Python2, `super` will only work if the the class hierarchy inherits from `object`.

If the superclass is declared as

```
class Foo:
   ...
```

you will get the error you see, because the class created is an old0style class tht doesn't support `super`

The superclass declaration needs to be

```
class Foo(object):
    ....
```

For example:

```
>>> class Foo:pass
... 
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super(Bar, self).__init__()
... 
>>> b = Bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

In Python3 old-style classes have been removed, so explicit inheritance from object is no longer required.

Comment: "class Foo(object):"  That did it.  Thanks snakecharmerb.